# How many passwords possible?

Tags: combinatorics

A password for a bank need to include **11** letters can be made from the $A,B,..Z$ letters (only upper case) such that the password must include the letter $A$ excatly 5 times and $Z$ exactly 3 times, how many different passwords can be made?

I find it hard to apply the conditions of the letters $A$ and $Z$, I know that in a general without conditions there is $26^{11}$ options, now I would like to understand the number of forbidden passwords.

Comment: How many ways are there to arrange the spots for the letter $A$? Now remove the $5$ spots for the letter $A$. How many ways are there to arrange the places for the three $B$s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $8$ places of the password are fixed, let's consider the remaining $3$ places which can be filled with the remaining $24$ letters.

The number of "$3-24$" passwords is $24^3$.

Now, consider a password composed by $5$ "A", $3$ "Z" and $3$ "*". The number of these passwords is $$\frac{11!}{5!3!3!}.$$

Notice that this number is evaluated using the formula of [permutations of multisets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Permutations_of_multisets).

Therefore, the total number of passwords satisfying your requirements is:

$$24^3 \cdot \frac{11!}{5!3!3!} = 127'733'760.$$

Notice that the "*" letters corresponds to the "$3-24$" passwords.

---

A more effective explanation is the following:

\begin{array}{ccccccccccc}
A & A & A & A & A & Z & Z & Z & * & * & * \\
A & A & A & A & A & Z & Z & * & Z & * & * \\
A & A & A & A & A & Z & * & Z & Z & * & * \\
& & & & \vdots \\
* & * & * & Z & Z & Z & A & A & A & A & A \\
\end{array}

The number of rows of this table is $\frac{11!}{5!3!3!}$.
For each row, you can form exactly $24^3$ passwords assigning different letters to "*"s.

Comment: Can you explain how did you derived the expression $\frac{11!}{5!3!3!}.$? how is it represent the number of passwords of the $A$ and $Z$?

Comment: @Sagigever references to this formula has been added to the answer. Please, take a look.

Comment: @Sagigever Permutations of multisets are a useful concept, but you do not need it for this question.

Comment: @Sagigever then, do you know the solution?

Comment: understood thank you

Comment: @Sagigever you are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

There are $11 \choose 5$ ways to choose the places for the 5 $A$s. After this is done, there are $6$ spots remaining, and so there are $6 \choose 3$ to choose the places for the 3 $Z$s.

There are now $11 - 5 - 3 = 3$ spots left. Now there are $24$ letters left to choose from (since $A$ and $Z$ have been used up), and the letters can be repeated, so there are $24^3$ ways to fill these $3$ spots.

Therefore the total is ${11 \choose 5} \cdot {6 \choose 3} \cdot 24^3 = 127 \ 733 \ 760 $.

Comment: Finally found all my mistakes: this matches up with the_candyman's answer which tells me all is good.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, note that **eight** of the letters are fixed. Now, the remaining three letters could be any of the letters except for $A$ and $Z$. There are ${}^{24}C_3$ combinations for this. Now, these 11 letters could interchange themselves in $11!$ ways.

But the interchanges among the $5$ $A$'s and $3$ $Z$'s are not significant. Hence, total number of permutations (interchanges) is
$$\frac{11!}{5!\cdot 3!} = 332640$$

By the multiplication principle, total number of passwords is
$${}^{24}C_3\times 332640 = 4039518160$$

Hope it helps :)